Keep awesome notification shown after action clicked
I have an app that shows a notification with with some action buttons that navigate to specific pages. The code below works fine but I want the notification to stay even after the actions are being clicked. Of course I am using awesome notifications package in flutter.
await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
              content: NotificationContent(
                  id: 80,
                  channelKey: 'basic_channel',
                  actionType: ActionType.SilentBackgroundAction,
                  wakeUpScreen: true,
                  roundedLargeIcon: true,
                  // displayOnBackground: true,
                  displayOnForeground: true,
                  autoDismissible: false,
                  // showWhen: true,
                  largeIcon: 'asset://assets/background.png',
                  notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigText,
                  // notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
                  // bigPicture: "asset://assets/background.png",
                  // roundedBigPicture: true,
                  title: result.$1,
                  body: result.$2,
                  category: NotificationCategory.Reminder,
                  chronometer: Duration.zero,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  // fullScreenIntent: true,
                  locked: true,
                  payload: {}),
              schedule: NotificationCalendar(
                hour: input!['key1'],
                minute: input['key2'],
                second: 0,
                timeZone: input['key3'],
                preciseAlarm: true,
              ),
              actionButtons: [
                NotificationActionButton(
                  key: 'open_calendar',
                  label: 'Calendar',
                  color: Colors.blue, //color works when fullScreenIntent: true,
                  actionType: ActionType.Default,
                ),
                NotificationActionButton(
                  key: 'open_dictionary',
                  color: Colors.green,
                  label: 'Dictionary',
                  actionType: ActionType.Default,
                ),
                NotificationActionButton(
                  key: 'dismiss',
                  color: Colors.red,
                  label: 'Dismiss',
                  actionType: ActionType.DismissAction,
                  isDangerousOption: true, //makes the color red
                ),
              ]);

I manipulated the properties but they it didn't work the way I want it to be.
